# CellForRowAtIndexPath returning the wrong cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, segue

I am running into an issue where cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning the wrong cell and therefore, it is seguing and performing other actions on the wrong cell.

I have built custom cells that are quite big because I am fitting some UIImageViews (+text +buttons), so a cell takes up the entire screen. When you scroll down and two cells are on the screen at the same time, if you tap on the top one, it segues to the content of the bottom one (same for button actions inside the cell).

I thought this might be specific to IB, so I rebuilt everything in code, but am still having the same behavior.

Is there any way to fix this and maintain the correct indexPaths?

Comment: not without a lot more info to go on.. but a hint: the framework is .. not often THAT wrong, so likely your implementation is buggy :/ anyway, please flesh out the question

Comment: Can you post the implementation?

Comment: No one would be able to help you without seeing your code

Comment: Need to see code, but a guess just in case: check cell height.

Comment: when you return a cell at cellForRowAtIndexpath remove all the subviews from it, this may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your perspective wrong.  cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't return wrong cells.  It should just return a fresh cell, which may have been recycled if you're using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier or similar.  In which case, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will return any old cell which may have just scrolled off the top.  It's your job to take the fresh cell (which may be a new cell or a recycled one) and stuff the correct values in it, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Then the cell it returns will be the "correct" one because you've just written all the correct values to it.  So I would look at your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath to make sure that correct values for the index path that you're passed are stuffed into the cell that cellForRowAtIndexPath returns.