# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns different cell for the same indexpath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to understand what is going wrong, because when I do a tableview update and the cellForRowAtIndexPath get called, the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not getting back the cell what I need.

It just a table view update, with the **absolutely same indexPath, and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil for the first time of update and creates another cell for it**. That s bad, because every update method called twice, that causing flashing for images

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[cellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    if ([cellClass isEqual:[ATTimeLineMealCell class]]) {
        NSLog(@"table view: %@",tableView);
        NSLog(@"CELL DATA: %@",cell);
        NSLog(@"Row: %ld , section: %ld",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);
    }

}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSLog(@"table view: %@",tableView);
        NSLog(@"CELL DATA UPDATE:%@",cell);
}
```

**Flow:**
Inserting a new cell
then make a reload on the cell (not reloadData)

And the log:

```
> 2018-04-26 15:53:26.214828+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table view:
> <ATQueryTableView: 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0;
> 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:
> 0x1c044f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0,
> -292}; contentSize: {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {292, 0, 0, 0}> 2018-04-26 15:53:26.215271+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA:
> <ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x1040aa800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame =
> (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4437de0>> 2018-04-26
> 15:53:26.215290+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] Row: 1 , section: 0 2018-04-26
> 15:53:26.216296+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table view: <ATQueryTableView:
> 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 375 667);
> clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c044f960>;
> layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0, -292}; contentSize:
> {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {292, 0, 0, 0}> 2018-04-26
> 15:53:26.216409+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA
> UPDATE:<ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x1040aa800; baseClass = UITableViewCell;
> frame = (0 80; 375 120); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x1c4437de0>>
> 
> 2018-04-26 15:53:28.456177+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table view:
> <ATQueryTableView: 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0;
> 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:
> 0x1c044f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0, 80};
> contentSize: {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {315, 0, 0, 0}>
> 2018-04-26 15:53:28.456308+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA:
> <ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x104162a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame =
> (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4437bc0>> 2018-04-26
> 15:53:28.456387+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] Row: 1 , section: 0 2018-04-26
> 15:53:28.457095+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table view: <ATQueryTableView:
> 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 375 667);
> clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c044f960>;
> layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0, 80}; contentSize:
> {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {315, 0, 0, 0}> 2018-04-26
> 15:53:28.457191+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA
> UPDATE:<ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x104162a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell;
> frame = (0 80; 375 120); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x1c4437bc0>>
> 
> 
> 2018-04-26 15:53:29.814609+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table view:
> <ATQueryTableView: 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0;
> 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:
> 0x1c044f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0, 80};
> contentSize: {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {315, 0, 0, 0}>
> 2018-04-26 15:53:29.816399+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA:
> <ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x1040aa800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame =
> (0 80; 375 120); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x1c4437de0>> 2018-04-26 15:53:29.816420+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] Row: 1
> , section: 0 2018-04-26 15:53:29.816792+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] table
> view: <ATQueryTableView: 0x10482a600; baseClass = UITableView; frame =
> (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:
> 0x1c044f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c00362a0>; contentOffset: {0, 80};
> contentSize: {375, 747}; adjustedContentInset: {315, 0, 0, 0}>
> 2018-04-26 15:53:29.816849+0200 Ate[6956:2981607] CELL DATA
> UPDATE:<ATTimeLineMealCell: 0x1040aa800; baseClass = UITableViewCell;
> frame = (0 80; 375 120); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x1c4437de0>>
```

**From the log it seems like when the update comes, it creates one more cell for the same indexPath:**

- original cell memory address: **0x1040aa800**
- newly generated but why?? memory address: **0x104162a00**

Comment: Your code is not real code, because you are not returning a cell. _Show real code_. Also, you are calling the wrong method. Do _not_ call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`! Call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Finally, cells are reused so there is no such thing as "the cell that I need"; you get the cell that you get, and your job is to prepare it for the index path where it is to be used in the table.

Comment: that will set cell to a new memory address which will return on that specific indexpath so that will be different.

Comment: The fact that you are worried about that _is the problem_. You are misunderstanding completely how table views and their cells work. Cells are reused. There is no correspondence between cell "memory address" and index path. The same cell can appear in different rows. Different cells can appear in the same row.

Comment: I know about reusable cells, but absolutely not understand if there is just one row in my tableview, why the update get call twice in a each times, for two cells in the same indexpath

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084833/cellforrowatindexpath-returning-the-wrong-cell/14088897#14088897

Answer (score 1):

> `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get called, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` not getting back the cell what I need

You are misunderstanding how table views work. Cells are reused. The same cell object might be used now in one row, now in another row. The same row might be occupied now by one cell object, now by another. There is no correspondence. It is completely not up to you, and completely irrelevant, what cell you get for a particular index path. Your job is to configure whatever cell object you get, so that it is correct *for that index path*.

Comment: But If I have just one row, why is it assigned to a new memory address on a reload

Comment: Why not? Please listen to what I'm telling you. The identity of the cell object is of _no interest to you_. If your code depends upon that, your code is _wrong_. Only _index path_ matters.

Comment: Thanks matt! You just saved my life explaining the idea of the workings.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get the exact cell back, use a unique cellReuseIdentifier for just that cell then it will prevent the cell from being reused. However for the UITableView, cell reusing is normal and it should be correctly implemented so the view won't take too much of the memory (because the cell out of the screen will be reused for new content). What you should care would only be how to clean up the cell and decorate it again with the new data rather than just get the old cell back at the same indexPath.